# Cannot connect Django 1.8.19 to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django

I am using Django 1.8.19 and SQL Server 2019, but I can't connect Django to SQL Server. How to fix it?

This is the error I am getting:

```
raise NotImplementedError('SQL Server v%d is not supported.' % ver)
NotImplementedError: SQL Server v15 is not supported.
```

These are my settings:

```py
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
'NAME': 'aaaa',
'USER': 'bbbb',
'PASSWORD': 'ccccc,
'HOST': 'zzzzz',
'PORT': '1433',
'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
'OPTIONS': {
    'host_is_server': True,
    'autocommit': True,
    'unicode_results': True,
    'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.2',
}
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And I suspect the error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: `tds_version=7.2` is from SQL Server 2005 days. Have you tried using `tds_version=7.4` instead, or maybe removing this option altogether?

Comment: I have change but still error,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mssql-django`

```
pip install mssql-django
```

then the on settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'YOUR_DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'DB_HOST',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```